# primitive recursion in the lambda calculus

Tags: recursion, lambda-calculus, primitive-recursion

I am having trouble finding out what a primitive subset of the lambda calculus would look like. I reference primitive recursion as shown here: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function".

These are the three base axioms:

- Constant function: The 0-ary constant function 0 is primitive recursive.
- Successor function: The 1-ary successor function S, which returns the successor of its argument (see Peano postulates), is primitive recursive. That is, S(k) = k + 1.
- Projection function: For every n≥1 and each i with 1≤i≤n, the n-ary projection function Pin, which returns its i-th argument, is primitive recursive.

Here is my confusion. In the LC zero is represented as `(λfx. x)`.
Next the successor functions is defined as `(λnfx. f (n f x))`. Because they are both axioms both of these functions can be classified as primitive. But when I apply the function suc to zero I get the encoding of the number one. Which is represented as the function `(λf.(λx.(f x)))`.  Now this number is neither zero or the suc function but the result of application. As such I do not see how this result function (value of 1) fits into the rule set. But very clearly a program with the number 1 in it is still primitive recursive. What am I not understanding here? While 1 is the suc to zero, once suc is applied it is neither suc, nor zero.

Comment: There are also "derivation rule", namely composition and recursion.

Comment: Of course @YuvalFilmus but as far as I could tell those did not affect the problem. Unless I have misunderstood in which case how do they help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, $1$ is primitive recursive according to the following proof:

- $0$ is primitive recursive (axiom)
- $\operatorname{suc}$ is primitive recursive (axiom)
- $1=\operatorname{suc}(0)$ is primitive recursive (composition)

Using this you can show that $1$ is *admissible*, that is if you add $1$ as an axiom, the resulting set of functions is still the primitive recursive functions.

Note that lambda calculus has absolutely nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: So just to clarify if I apply suc to zero, then the function that is the result is also primitive recursive? It will then not be possible for that function to introduce Turing complete behavior?

Comment: That's right – you can use composition and primitive recursion in defining primitive recursive functions. It says so clearly in the definition. Even using these rules, you can't obtain all computable functions.